# How can I remove the redundant file name display in Finder's contextual menu items?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I'd like to customize the contextual menu for icons on the desktop. It appears when one clicks a file while pressing the control key. Many of the items in the contextual menu contain the full file name next to the action, and because of this it's not so easy to find a menu item sometimes. So, I would like to remove the file name that displays next to the action for these contextual menu items.

For example:
There is a file on the desktop named "Notes.txt". Clicking on it while pressing control (or just by right clicking), and the contextual menu will display, containing items like `Compress "Notes.txt"`, `Burn "Notes.txt" to Disc…`, and `Copy "Notes.txt"`.

[image]

How can I change these menu items to simply display as `Compress`, `Burn to Disc…`, and `Copy`?

Comment: This is actually called a "contextual menu". It's still kind of hard to understand what your issue is. Does your contextual menu look broken or corrupt in some way? Attaching a screenshot to your question would help. (Use command-shift-4 to start taking a screenshot.)

Comment: Thank you for telling me the exact name. I tried to upload the screen shot. But, I have no enough rights to attach it and Sorry about my English level. I will try BonzaiThePenguin tells me the way in a few days.

Comment: Even if you can't embed an image, you could still upload it to imgur (or somewhere else) and include a plain text link. Then someone with more reputation could edit your post for you to include the screenshot the normal way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Warning** This is untested. Make sure you back up any modified files!

1. Find the Finder application here:

   ```
   Macintosh HD ▸ System ▸ Library ▸ CoreServices ▸ Finder.app
   ```
2. Control-click on the Finder and choose "Show Package Contents"
3. Go to Contents ▸ Resources ▸ English.lproj ▸ Localizable.strings, and drag that file to the Desktop. It will be copied.
4. Open the Terminal (either use Launchpad or find it in Macintosh HD ▸ Applications ▸ Utilities), paste this line of text, and press enter:

   ```
   plutil -convert xml1 /Users/(username)/Desktop/Localizable.strings
   ```

   Make sure you replace (username) with your user account name.
5. Open the Localizable.strings file on the Desktop in TextEdit, and locate this line:

   ```
   <string>Copy “^1”</string>
   ```
6. Change it to this and save:

   ```
   <string>Copy</string>
   ```
7. Do the same thing for any other strings you wish to modify (Compress, Burn, Quick Look)
8. Switch back to the Terminal, paste this line into it, and press enter:

   ```
   plutil -convert binary1 /Users/(username)/Desktop/Localizable.strings
   ```
9. Drag the Localizable.strings file from the Desktop back into the English.lproj folder. You will need to enter your administrator password for this. **Also make sure you create a backup of the original Localizable.strings file**.
10. Log out and log back in.

Comment: Thank you very much for telling me! I will try this soon. Buy the way, If I would like to know like this way. Could you advice me what should I study about?

Comment: It worked! So far so good. Thank you very much for the information. I'm happy with new contextual menu. Unfortunately, I don't have a right to use "Vote up". Could you someone do it for me?

Comment: @user3171796 I would, but I still can't tell what your issue is. When you right-click a file, are you getting _duplicate_ menu items? That would indicate you have a problem with another piece of software on your computer, and editing the strings file is just going to be covering up a larger problem.

Comment: @NReilingh No, What I would like to do is BonzaiThePenguin gave me information is covered. The way can change the display name of item of contextual menu. My problem was when I see contextual menu always the file name is the front of action such duplicate and compress. It's not so easy to find the action that was my problem.

Comment: OH. I get it now. Now that I understand, I can edit your question to be more clear.